# How do I test a Service with calls to an external API in Spring

Tags: java, spring-boot, microsoft-graph-api, junit5, wiremock

Okay, so I am pretty new to testing and Spring Boot in general, so please correct me if I am doing something completely wrong here in the first place.

As a project my team and I are making a Web Application using Spring Boot where we are making calls to the Microsoft Graph API in some of our services. See this service for cancelling an event in a user's calendar:

```
import com.microsoft.graph.authentication.IAuthenticationProvider;
import com.microsoft.graph.models.extensions.IGraphServiceClient;
import com.microsoft.graph.requests.extensions.GraphServiceClient;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;


@Service
public class CancelEventService {

    public void cancelEvent(final String token, final String id) {

        IAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = iHttpRequest -> iHttpRequest.addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
        IGraphServiceClient graphServiceClient = GraphServiceClient.builder().authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider).buildClient();

        graphServiceClient.me().events(id)
                .buildRequest()
                .delete();
    }
}
```

This is working great, but I have been struggling for a couple of days with how to write unit tests for this. The way I see it, I want to either make mocks of the GraphServiceClient, or use a tool like WireMock to make the request go to a mockserver and return some values I configure.

I've tried doing both, but I can't make mocks of GraphServiceClient because it is not a Bean in my project, so I can't figure out how I should proceed to make an implementation I can autowire in to my Service.

When it comes to WireMock I am not even sure I understand if it is capable of doing what I want to, and if it is, I sure haven't been able to configure it correctly (note that we are using JUnit 5 for this project). A simple example where you make a GET-request to Google.com and return "Hello" via WireMock would suffice to get me going here.

Any concrete examples of what I should do, or even just a nod in the right direction would be well appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a follow up on this, we found a solution to the problem by creating a class
GraphServiceClientImpl with a method that returns an instantiated GraphServiceClient.

```
@Component
public class GraphServiceClientImpl {

    public IGraphServiceClient instantiateGraphServiceClient(final String token) {
        IAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = iHttpRequest -> iHttpRequest.addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
        return GraphServiceClient.builder().authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider).buildClient();
    }
}
```

```
@Service
public class CancelEventService{

    private GraphServiceClientImpl graphServiceClientImpl;

    public CancelEventService(final GraphServiceClientImpl graphServiceClientImpl) {
        this.graphServiceClientImpl = graphServiceClientImpl;
    }

    public void cancelEvent(final String token, final String id) {

        IGraphServiceClient graphServiceClient = graphServiceClientImpl.instantiateGraphServiceClient(token);

        graphServiceClient
                .me()
                .events(id)
                .buildRequest()
                .delete();
    }
}
```

Then, our test:

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class CancelEventServiceTest {

    @Mock
    private GraphServiceClientImpl graphServiceClientImpl;

    @InjectMocks
    private CancelEventService cancelEventService;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    void cancelEvent_Successful() {

        //given
        IGraphServiceClient serviceClientMock = mock(IGraphServiceClient.class, RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS);
        given(graphServiceClientImpl.instantiateGraphServiceClient(anyString())).willReturn(serviceClientMock);

        //when
        cancelEventService.cancelBooking("Token", "1");

        //then
        verify(serviceClientMock, times(1)).me();
    }
}
```

Probably not the optimal solution, but it works. Any other takes on this would be welcome!

Answer (score 4):

Well, I cannot assure you that it will work but it will give you a better landscape of the situation:

1) So first, we need to make a slight change on your service.
Need to extract IGraphServiceClient from the method so we can mock it later, see:

```
@Service
public class CancelEventService {

   private IGraphServiceClient graphServiceClient;

   @Autowired
   public CancelEventService(IGraphServiceClient graphServiceClient){
       this.graphServiceClient = graphServiceClient;
   }

    public void cancelEvent(final String token, final String id) {

        IAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = iHttpRequest -> iHttpRequest.addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
        graphServiceClient = GraphServiceClient.builder().authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider).buildClient();

        graphServiceClient.me().events(id)
                .buildRequest()
                .delete();
    }
}
```

2) The test would look like this:
(Notice that all we are using here is included in spring boot test module, so you shouldn't need to add anything to the project dependencies)

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class CancelEventServiceTest {

  private IGraphServiceClient graphServiceClientMock;

  private CancelEventService serviceToBeTested;

  @Before
  public void setUp(){

    graphServiceClientMock = Mockito.mock(IGraphServiceClient.class, RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS);
    serviceToBeTested = new CancelEventService(graphServiceClientMock);
  }

  @Test
  public void test_1() {


    serviceToBeTested.cancelEvent("token", "id");

    verify(graphServiceClientMock, times(1)).me().events("id").buildRequest()
        .delete();
  }
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Problably you should do the same for IAuthenticatorProvider, let me know and I'll correct the post

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering!

The problem with your solution, like I might have explained poorly when stating that "I can't make mocks of GraphServiceClient because it is not a Bean in my project", is that I have no implementations of IGraphServiceClient, which is an interface provided by the Microsoft dependency we are using for communicating with the Graph API. 

When trying to set up an autowired constructor like you suggest, I get the error "Could not autowire. No beans of IGraphServiceClient type found", because there is no concrete implementation of it in my project. Any suggestions?